# Connect to SQL Server from Code Connection MakeCode

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to connect to Microsoft SQL Server from Microsoft MakeCode for Code Connection? I don't think it is possible, but it might be. And if it isn't, can you connect to a different database?

**Edit:** I'm using JavaScript

Comment: your tags seem to contradict the question

Comment: Are you sure you're at the right site? This is meant for games. If not, edit your question to reflect the tags.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: ... and how in the world did this question (a) get two upvotes and (b) not get closed or even enter the close vote queue in 2021.

Comment: Also, Microsoft MakeCode and Code Connection should be Minecraft Education Edition features, so the question was also tagged wrong